# MS SQL Server Parse Name To Get First And Last

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table with sample data like this

```
Create Table #Test
(
    fullname varchar(140)
)

Insert Into #Test Values ('Jose Mendez (ealica)'), ('Bob Smith (home)'), ('Frank Goza (webuser)')
```

And I want to be able to select from the field to get two values `firstname` and `lastname`

Like this

```
Select
FirstName = 
,LastName =
FROM #Test
```

For the first insert I would expect it to look like this

```
FirstName = Jose
LastName = Mendez
```

With SQL Server 2016 how can I do this?

Comment: Why not create a table with 3 columns?

Comment: Also have you considered what happens if you have a name like `John Jackenhiemer Smith III (silly name)`

Comment: @Hogan - this is how data is in the server, I need to parse it out --- and it's always first name (space) last name (space) userlevel

Comment: @Hogan - unfortunately I have no way of controlling how the data is insert into the server, I must manipulate it once it's in the databas

Comment: What will you do if one of the people is `Oscar De La Hoya (boxer)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that you will have first name + white space + last name + category, then the following code designed as a TVF may do it.

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetFirstLastName(@s1 nvarchar(512))
RETURNS @name TABLE(FirstName nvarchar(100), LastName nvarchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @firstSpace int;
  DECLARE @fName varchar(100);
  DECLARE @lName varchar(100);
  
  /*TRIM the string to get rid of initial spaces*/
  SET @s1 = TRIM(@s1)
  /*find the first space based on the trimmed string*/
  SET @firstSpace = CHARINDEX(' ', @s1, 0)
  /*grab out the first part of the string - first name*/
  SET @fName = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@s1, 0, @firstSpace))
  /*remove the first part that we have just grabbed*/
  SET @lName = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@s1, @firstSpace + 1, LEN(@s1)))
  /*get the last name*/
  SET @lName = TRIM(SUBSTRING(@lName, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', @lName, 0)))
  
  INSERT INTO @name
  VALUES(@fName, @lName)
RETURN
END
```

Having created the TVF as per above you can execute against your table as so:

```
SELECT f.*
FROM #Test t
CROSS APPLY dbo.fn_GetFirstLastName(t.fullname) f
```

I hope the above helps.

Oh, as a side note: the code above can definitely be optimized and simplified - I just threw it together as an example. There are also other ways that this can be done.

Answer (score -1):

Ok if I was in this situation this is what I would do.

Create a new table called "PARSEDNAME"

1. Insert all the full name values into that table in column 1 (fullname)
2. Run a query that counts the spaces and puts it in a new column (space_count)
3. Select all the rows that have a count greater than 2.   Show that list to the client and ask them how to resolve those.
4. select everything up to first space put it into a column called first name
5. select everything from first space to 2nd space and put it into a column called last name
6. select the rest and put it in a column called category.

-- Done.

You might ask why all the steps.  The answer is simple -- there are going to be problems and issues at every step you need to resolve.  By doing it as separate steps you break the problem down into manageable and resolvable sub problems.

Comment: i can get everything to the left of the first space (aka first name) no problem.  I haven't been able to get the syntax to get everything between the 2nd and 3rd space (aka last name) yet.  I've spent hours on google looking

Comment: @user2676140 -- in all those hours did you type typing "split a name in sql" into the search bar of this website?